# React use componentWillReceiveProps to re-render the component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I can't figure out how to make my componenet re-render when the value of `this.props.user` changes. Initially the value of `this.props.user` is null but it changes to an actual value seconds after. Below I am showing the child component. The parent component maps the store state to it's props and I pass it to the child component class below.

```js
export class UserInfoComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {user: this.props.user}
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    this.setState({user: this.props.user})
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.user)
    return (
      <h1>{this.state.user.firstName}</h1>
    );

    return (
      <h1>loading</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`componentWillReceiveProps` receives `nextProps` as an argument. with the code you presently have you are just setting user back to its current state. You need to use the `nextProps` argument provided.

```js
export class UserInfoComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {user: this.props.user}
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({user: nextProps.user})
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.user)
    return (
      <h1>{this.state.user.firstName}</h1>
    );

    return (
      <h1>loading</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why to use state ? Props change will already lead to re-render of the component.

Comment: The primary difference here is that in the questioners example they are converting their passed in props to its own internal state. This only happens once when the component is rendered so anywhere that `this.state.user` i referenced will always reference the first value that was ever passed in since it happens during the construction of the component. `componentWillReceiveProps` updates the state when the parent component has passed in new props but this doens't happen naturally and why converting props into state is usually an anti-pattern

Comment: My point is to say , you don t have to listen to props changes to rerender a component. Questioner might not know that. I didn t ask about the difference.

Comment: @finalfreq if converting the props into state is anti-pattern, is there another thing that I can do to fix my component? The reason I used the `this.setState` is because I thought that it re-renders the component

Comment: @pbgnz in that case just remove state all together and use `this.props.user` instead of `this.state.user`. Your component will always rerender if its props or state have changed. You should only use state if its something that the component is going to change based on some action whether it be a user or loading data from an api call.